# 3ds Max 2013 Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, 3dsmax

I was trying to configure `Max SDK (3ds Max 2013)` within Visual Studio 2010 (SP1).

Every thing goes well and I successfully got the templates "3ds Max Plugin Wizard". Now As I am creating the project, the process fails.

Error Message:`"Creating Project test_proj - Project Creation Fails`"

I had followed this [link](http://masteranza.wordpress.com/2008/12/27/solution-vs-c-2008-project-creation-failed-bug/) and done all the suggested Registry Editing, But problem didn't resolved. I also tried the samples from `"Autodesk\maxsdk\samples"` and `"Autodesk\maxsdk\howto"` but unable to build it sucessfully.

Please suggest the solution for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - make sure you have the files installed properly and make sure you can access them properly. User access control can cause problems when using visual studio, you can solve this by right-clicking visual studio and run it as administrator.
If user access control is on and you do not run it as administrator then it will lock the folders needed by visual studio.

You can also lower the 'User access control' setting and reboot.

Then you have to make sure you have set up the path correctly in the wizard file:

> Open the 3ds MaxPluginWizard. vsz file (in the
>   maxsdk\Howto\3dsmaxPluginWizard directory root) in a text editor and
>   edit the ABSOLUTE PATH parameter to reflect the new location of the
>   3dsmaxPluginWizard root directory. Do not add a backslash after the
>   directory name.

```
Param="ABSOLUTE_PATH = [Absolute Path Location of 3dsmaxPluginWizard Root Directory]"
```

> Copy the following files from the 3dsmaxPluginWizard root to the
>   'VC\vcprojects' directory under your Visual Studio installation
>   directory (e.g. C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   2010\VC\vcprojects):

3dsmaxPluginWizard.ico
3dsmaxPluginWizard.vsdir
3dsmaxPluginWizard.vsz

By installing the SDK to it's default location, and editing the file path, and then making sure you can access the folders properly it should work.
I've done it like this for many releases by now.